# Docker compose V2: unknown shorthand flag 'f' (windows)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently running docker desktop version 20.10.22 (build 3a2c30b, fresh install) on Windows (using wsl2), but `docker compose` commands with the `-f` flag do not work correctly. Since I'm using docker compose V2 (checked the option in the docker desktop settings), my commands are with a space instead of a hyphen.  I get the following message when running any `docker compose` command using `-f`:

> unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f See 'docker --help'.

Specifically, I'm running the [FIWARE NGSI-LD tutorials](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.NGSI-LD). All docker compose commands that are used within those tutorials fail. The commands can be found in the `services` file for each tutorial. For example, a command that fails (saying that the `-f` flag does not exist) within the [Short-Term-History tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Short-Term-History/tree/64c5020b146bbeff2d7ea17b6b72b2f095e716fb) is the following:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose/mintaka.yml -p fiware up -d --remove-orphans --renew-anon-volumes
```

The weird thing is that `docker compose --help` and `docker compose --version` both return the output from respectively `docker --help` and `docker --version`, **as if it excludes the `compose` keyword**. The output of the above command also refers to the standard docker help command instead of the docker compose help.

**UPDATE: Docker excludes the `compose` keyword between docker and the rest of the command. Replacing compose with a random string of letters gives the same effect. It seems as if it cannot recognize the `compose` keyword.**

The old `docker-compose` is not installed so that does not work either. Running `which docker-compose` returns the `docker-compose.exe` location, inside the `.../Docker/resources/bin` folder. Running `which docker compose` returns the location of `docker.exe`. The `.../Docker/resources/bin` folder is inside the path environment variable.

Does anybody know what the problem might be? I've searched countless websites but did not find any solutions for this problem yet.

Kind regards

Comment: Please edit your post and add the exact command you use that fails

Comment: @HansKilian I edited the question to include the specific command.

Comment: doing ```snap remove docker;
apt purge 'docker*';
apt install docker.io docker-compose-v2;``` fixed it for me on Ubuntu 22.04 , dunno why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled docker desktop with the same installer (also same version) and this resolved the problem weirdly enough...

The only difference between my old and new installation was that I already had wsl2 installed this time.

Comment: Weird enough, that was the exact scenario I had. And your answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have in running processes when I run `docker compose events`:

[image: docker compose processes]

Please check if you have all these directories and files. Then we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: I will add an answer asap, but weirdly enough, reinstalling docker desktop (same installer, same version) resolved the problem... The only difference between my old and new installation was that I already had wsl installed this time.